# c++ json-nlohmann accessing the list elements

Tags: c++, json

I'm trying to use [json-nlohmann](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) library to read JSON files in C++

So far I got along with it preatty well, but now I'm trying to access elements of the list in given json. JSON:

```
{
    "GameMap": "path_to_game_map",
    "Objects": [
        { "object_1": { "Transform": { "Position": { "X": 1, "Y": 2 }, "Rotation": { "X": 3.5, "Y": 8.2 }, "Scale": { "X": 1, "Y":1 } },
                        "Components": [
                        { "0": { "data": { "some_data": "false" } } },
                        { "1": { "data": { "some_data": "false" } } },
                        { "2": { "data": { "some_data": "false" } } }
                        ] } },
        { "object_2": { "Transform": { "Position": { "X": 1, "Y": 2 }, "Rotation": { "X": 3.5, "Y": 8.2}, "Scale": { "X": 1, "Y":1 } },
                        "Components": [
                        { "0": { "data": { "some_data": "false" } } },
                        { "1": { "data": { "some_data": "false" } } },
                        { "2": { "data": { "some_data": "false" } } }
                        ] } }                   
    ]
}
```

Where I'm trying to access each Component and read it's key value.

I've got an object out for every Component. But I just cannot figure out how to read its key and value.

Help! Please.

Comment: what you want get as result?

Comment: As result I want to read a Key of the Object (0, 1, 2...) and get the Data out to parse it.

Comment: Show the code you have written so far for reading the object

Comment: Yes. I can see the object with `is_object()` and I can see it in Debugger. But I cannot get its Key and Value - Or maybe I'm missing something???

Answer (score 7):

When you iterate a JSON object, say `j`, you can access the key and value like this:

```
for (json::iterator it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it.key() << " : " << it.value() << "\n";
}
```

you can also now use `for (auto& element : j.items())` and then `element.key()` and `element.value()` inside the loop.